# How to open link in new windows by _blank and in background?

Tags: javascript, hyperlink

for a normal link `<a href="xxx" target="_blank">`, the link will open at a new window(or tab).

I like to know if there's a way to open it in background, and keep current window still active.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

After you `open` the new window (we'll call it `newWindow`), do this:

```
newWindow.blur();
window.focus();
```

This is usually called a "pop-under." Opening the window won't usually work unless it's initiated by a user action like a mouse click, due to pop-up blockers built into most web browsers.

Just remember to get a handle to your new window when you open it.

```
var newWindow = window.open(...);
```

Also, if your pop-under is loading content from another domain, you'll need to do the `blur`/`focus` thing *before* you send the window to its destination, otherwise you'll run into the same-origin problem.

---

HTML:

```
<a href="xxx" target="_blank" onclick="return popUnder(this);">
```

JS:

```
function popUnder(node) {
    var newWindow = window.open("about:blank", node.target, "width=500,height=500");
    newWindow.blur();
    window.focus();
    newWindow.location.href = node.href;
    return false;
}
```

Comment: How can i open link in new tab in unity3d game?
  **For example** i am using this code but its opening in window not in tab  
`Application.ExternalEval("var win=window.open('http://unity3diy.blogspot.com/','_blank');win.focus();");` 
 any solution for this?

Comment: @craiglerr what browser are you using? I'm sure it's implementation dependent, but as far as I can tell Chrome and Firefox will both open it in a tab if the third argument to `open` is omitted, and in a window if the argument is present and not empty.

Comment: Hey i am using chrome and unity webplayer. and this script opening tab in the new window, not in the tab.

Answer (score 1):

This is typically a browser preference. But if you can somehow get a hold to the other window with javascript (maybe by hooking up the onclick event and open the link with window.open you could do the typical pop-under trick:

```
otherWindow.blur();
window.focus();
```