# Can the new tab be opened in the background in HTML Form target="_blank"?

Tags: firefox-addon, firefox-addon-restartless

Adding `target="_blank"` to `form` will post & open the result in a new tab (or window).

```
<form target="_blank" enctype="multipart/form-data" 
      action="https://www.example.com/" method="POST">
  <!-- more HTML -->
</form>

// and from the addon form.submit();
// there isn't any button or link to be clicked by the user
```

By default, the new tab will be the selected/foreground tab.
Is it possible to control/set the foreground/background status of the new tab?

**N.B.** The purpose is to give the **USER** the choice of opening in the foreground or background by using a modifier key (like for example shift or Ctrl).

The code is part of a Firefox addon (not part of site JavaScript).

Comment: I can only imagine this would be very bad in terms of evil people doing evil things and hence you cannot control that

Comment: possible duplicate of [I need to to open a new window in the background with JavaScript, and make sure the original is still focused](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2181464/i-need-to-to-open-a-new-window-in-the-background-with-javascript-and-make-sure) or [How to open link in new windows by _blank and in background?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9544519/how-to-open-link-in-new-windows-by-blank-and-in-background) or [Open a new tab in the background?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10812628/open-a-new-tab-in-the-background) and probably a lot more dupes

Comment: @PeeHaa ... I understand the concern. The purpose is to give the USER the choice, ie by holding shift key or other modifier. I will add this to the original question.

Comment: There already is such a thing (at least in Chrome): ctrl + click

Comment: I just checked and on win FF it works the same. ctrl+click opens new tab in background

Comment: @PeeHaa tnx ... Did you check it with a link or a form?

Comment: Tried a link in FF and form in chrome. Apparently FF doesn't allow it in form :(

Comment: For XUL windows you can use this method here: [GitHubGIST ::  Noitidart / _ff-addon-snippet-OpenXULWindowBehind.js](https://gist.github.com/Noitidart/9b9ef5460a9a8b024324)

Comment: However to do this with a form click, maybe you should listen to tab open and on open if its the location you expect than switch to tab before it. Or temporarily set all new tabs to open in background then open the tab then revert the setting to user default

Comment: i nominate to re-open, this is different from linked answers as its in the firefox addon scope.

Comment: @Noitidart ..Tnx.. it was in Firefox Addon scope but got diverted to nowhere (with a dup label). I gave up looking for answers and went back to my own testing and manged it in a totally different way with gBrowser (much easier, 2 lines, testing now). ;)

Comment: @erosman Please share that man in this topic here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25063835/how-to-control-opening-of-next-link?lq=1