# How to control opening of next link

Tags: firefox-addon

I was wondering how to control the next link the opens. Like I want to capture it and then redirect it to like open in new tab, or new background tab, or new window, or new pop behind window.

This is to help this guys question that was unnecesarily duplicated:
[Can the new tab be opened in the background in HTML Form target="_blank"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25058728/can-the-new-tab-be-opened-in-the-background-in-html-form-target-blank)

It also helps me with my own stuff please.

Thanks

@errosman if you put [javascript](/questions/tagged/javascript) then those javascript guys invade and do lots of topic closing etc. when it shouldnt be.

Comment: True... I added the JavaScript tag, since it is JS and it shows syntax highlighting.. but as you said, users may mistake privilege/browser level/context JS, with page scope content JS :(