# Open a page with window.open without leaving the current page

Tags: jquery, window.open

I am creating a discount coupon site, and wanted to do so: to open a coupon on my website, the advertiser's store would be loaded into a new window, but you remain in my coupon page where the coupon code would be presented and the information to use it.

How can I do this? An example can be seen in CouponXL site (http://demo.powerthemes.club/themes/couponxl/coupons/).

Comment: possible duplicate of [I need to open a new window in the background with JavaScript, and make sure the original is still focused](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2181464/i-need-to-open-a-new-window-in-the-background-with-javascript-and-make-sure-the)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9544519/how-to-open-link-in-new-windows-by-blank-and-in-background

Comment: Adersh, It's what I'm trying, but I can not stay on my page.